# Adding Notes to Profile Summary

Tags: profile

I'm new to CiviCRM and am trying to make it very streamlined for my team. They mentioned that having the Notes (adding ability and listng previous notes) on the Contact Profile's Summary tab would be best for quick access. I'm wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome Samantha. Hopefully one of the volunteers here will be able to give you a steer. I suspect the risk would be that someone with a lot of Notes will get a very long Summary page. I will make a suggestion below too

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) which lets you modify the layout of the Contact screen, and in doing so lets you pull in Dashlets from Reports

The problem i can see though it that there is no obvious report builder for Notes.

Depending on your CMS you could potentially do this via a CMS tool such as Views in Drupal, and then add the Block as a Dashlet on that Summary Layout tool.

I have not tested the above but it is one concept to rule in/out. Otherwise a small extension that modifies the templates involved may give you what you need but would require someone with developer skills. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you please send that hyperlink again? The one in the comment seems broken. Appreciate it!

Comment: sorry. try now.

Comment: another approach is to use Activities instead of Notes and have a Dashlet of Activities on the Summary Layout page